# Parsing timestamp with "T" between date and time

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to parse a timestamp I received from database, I have tried multiple parsing string, but every each of them did not work. I am trying to extract the date and clock.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            // error here!
            SimpleDateFormat postgre = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddXHH:mm:ss.ms", Locale.getDefault());
            Date d = postgre.parse("2019-08-07T09:51:17.222Z");

            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(d));
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(d));
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

yes, I need to use legacy class.

Comment: So what is the problem with current code? Because if  the `T` and `Z` bother you just use `string.Replace()` to  convert it to spaces

Comment: why is it that when we post a question, suddenly we got it right? i will delete my question now

Comment: Is ok, that can happen.

Comment: Excuse me, I know this sounds a bit ignorant, but what makes you think that you need to use the legacy date and time classes? have you got an evil boss who says so? `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is notoriously troublesome, and java.time, the modern Java date and time API, has been backported to Java 6 and 7 and further adapted to Android under API level 26.

Comment: If it’s in a database, wouldn’t it make sense to retrieve it from the database as a Timestamp or Instant, rather than as a String?

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Simple one-liner using the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy classes such as `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
java.time.Instant
.parse( 
    "2019-08-07T09:51:17.222Z"
)
.atOffset( 
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
)
.toLocalDate()
```

For time-of-day portion, call `toLocalTime()`.

To see the same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Then call `toLocalDate` and `LocalTime`.

## Details

Parse using modern class, `Java.time.Instant`.

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-08-07T09:51:17.222Z" ) ;
```

Generate an ISO 8601 string.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

To write to database, convert to sibling class `OffsetDateTime`. While support for `Instant` is optional in JDBC 4.2 and later, your JDBC driver is required to support `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

If you want to see the date and the time-of-day for that moment as seen in UTC (as opposed to some time zone), extract a `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime lt = odt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Best to avoid the terrible legacy class `java.util.Date`. But if you must, you can convert back and forth using new to/from methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Likewise, when receiving a `Date`, immediately convert to an `Instant`. Then proceed with your business logic.

```
Instant instant = myDate.toInstant() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct pattern is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`. I forgot to use the capital S for milliseconds.

Comment: It’s a lot closer, but still not entirely correct. `Z` is an offset (of zero) from UTC and needs to be parsed as such, not as a literal, or you will get wrong times on the vast majority of JVMs.